# How to return `SETOF RECORD` type from a function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql, return-query

I'm trying to create a function which will return setof record. I want to use the function as follows:

```sql
SELECT city_name FROM set_city(1, 1, 'ExampleName');
```

My function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_city(_city_id integer, _country_id integer, _city_name varchar)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  result RECORD;
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM geo_cities gc WHERE gc.id = _city_id) THEN
    UPDATE geo_cities
    SET country_id = _country_id, city_name = _city_name
    WHERE id = _city_id
    RETURNING * INTO result;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO geo_cities(id, country_id, city_name)
    VALUES (_city_id, _country_id, _city_name)
    RETURNING * INTO result;
  END IF;
  -- It's wrong
  RETURN QUERY SELECT result;
END;
$$
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change the return statement:

```
...
        -- It's wrong
        -- RETURN QUERY SELECT result;
        RETURN NEXT result; -- that's good
...
```

However, a column definition list is required for functions returning "record", so you would have to add it in every query:

```
SELECT city_name FROM set_city(1, 1, 'ExampleName') 
    AS (id int, country_id int, city_name text);
```

In fact the function returns a single row of the type `geo_cities` and you do not need `setof`:

```
DROP FUNCTION set_city(_city_id integer, _country_id integer, _city_name varchar);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_city(_city_id integer, _country_id integer, _city_name varchar)
RETURNS geo_cities
LANGUAGE plpgsql
as $$
DECLARE
        result geo_cities;
BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM geo_cities gc WHERE gc.id = _city_id)
        THEN
                UPDATE geo_cities
                SET country_id = _country_id, city_name = _city_name
                WHERE id = _city_id
                RETURNING * INTO result;
        ELSE
                INSERT INTO geo_cities(id, country_id, city_name)
                VALUES (_city_id, _country_id, _city_name)
                RETURNING * INTO result;
        END IF;
        RETURN result;
END;
$$;

SELECT city_name FROM set_city(1, 1, 'ExampleName');
```

Note that you can get the same functionality in a single SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO geo_cities(id, country_id, city_name)
VALUES (1, 1, 'ExampleName')
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET 
    country_id = excluded.country_id, 
    city_name = excluded.city_name
RETURNING *;
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can create `my_func()` which returns `SETOF RECORD` type with a `RETURN NEXT` or `RETURN QUERY` statement as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE 
  row RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR row IN VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller') LOOP
    RETURN NEXT row; -- Here
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller'); -- Here
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` returns 2 rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func() AS (first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT);
 first_name | last_name
------------+-----------
 John       | Smith
 David      | Miller
(2 rows)
```

In addition, you can create `my_func()` which returns `TABLE()` with a `RETURN NEXT` or `RETURN QUERY` statement as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT) AS $$
BEGIN
  FOR first_name, last_name IN VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller') LOOP
    RETURN NEXT; -- Here
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller'); -- Here
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` returns 2 rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func();
 first_name | last_name
------------+-----------
 John       | Smith
 David      | Miller
(2 rows)
```

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
    my_func
----------------
 (John,Smith)
 (David,Miller)
(2 rows)
```